# The boundary of a manifold has empty boundary

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, diffeomorphism

It is a known fact, for example well explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554156/the-boundary-of-an-n-manifold-is-an-n-1-manifold), that the boundary of an $n$ manifold is an $n-1$ manifold, and the proof shows essentialy that properly restricted charts which parametrize $M$ parametrize also $\partial M$, with open set of a lower dimension, $n-1$.

My question is : I have to show that $\partial M$ has no boundary, or is implicit somehow having shown that $\partial M$ is parametrizable with open sets of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1} ?$ If so, why ?

Because for my definition of boundary I don't see how this should be implicit.

My definition is $p \in \partial M \iff p \in \phi(U \cap \left\lbrace x_n = 0\right\rbrace)$ i.e is the image of $\partial \mathbb{H}^n \cap U$, (where $U$ is the open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the intersection with closed half space $U \cap \mathbb{H}^n$ is a diffeomorphism with an open set of the manifold $V$).

How should I prove it ? It could be useful using [this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982691/a-local-diffeomorphism-can-map-a-boundary-point-to-an-interior-point) ?

I'd like to understand the answer given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95706/boundary-of-the-boundary-of-a-manifold-is-empty) previous question, which seems the way I should prove, it but I don't understand how the fact follows easily from the definitions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By definition, you $\partial M$ is endowed with charts that "look like" an open subset $U\cap \Bbb R^{n-1}$.

Comment: The set $U \cap \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is open in $\partial \mathbb{H}^n$, right ? But my question is, why parametrizing $\partial M$ with open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ doesn't require to show that $\partial \partial M$ is empty ? (with the definition given above)

Comment: @jacopoburelli A neighbourhood cannot look like $U\cap \Bbb r^{n-1}$ and $U\cap \partial \Bbb H^{n-1}$ at the same time

Comment: I don't think $U$ is the same; Besides, are you using that open sets of different dimension can't be diffeomorphic ?

Comment: I can use the definition of $\partial S$ as the subset of $S$ whose points don't have neighboorhoods homeomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Taking $S = \partial M$ we have that $\partial \partial M$ is the set of the points that don't have neighboorhoods homeomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$? And from here because $\partial M $ has been parametrized with open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is there was a point in $\partial \partial M$ we would have a contradiction ?